# Symfony 2 - hide the whole website with a HTTP Authentication dialog

Tags: security, symfony, firewall

I am using Symfony 2 for building a website.

The work is in progress (therefore I don't want users or search engines to access it) but my client wants to see my progress. I was thinking an easy solution was to protect the whole website with HTTP authentication using the mechanism provided by the Symfony 2 security functionality.

I am using FOSUserBundle as the website will have users that need to register and login.

This is my security.yml, which works great:

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    encoders:
        "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface": sha512

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true     

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/account, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Therefore I was trying to add something else on top of it, to allow the website to be protected by HTTP Authentication.
I changed the file to:

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager
        whole_website_provider:
            users:
                ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }           

    encoders:
        "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface": sha512

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
        whole_website:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Demo Area"       

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/account, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Basically I added the `whole_website_provider` provider, the `whole_website` firewall and an extra `access_control`.
But that didn't work: when I access the website, I get redirected to the login form, that's it.

Have you got any idea whether I can do it and how?

N.B.: I would prefer not to use any Apache feature for it.

Comment: What happens if you put the `whole_website` firewall first? Don't forget to clear the cache.

Comment: @gilden: that shows the authentication box, at least but I can't find a way to authenticate correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have time to give proper advice, but I'm guessing you also need to explicitly set the user provider for `whole_website` or Sf2 will use the first one. What PéCé is suggesting works as well, I guess, but being somewhat ocd, I would take on the difficult, yet more elegant solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my opinion, what you need is not to manage users with HTTP authentication but to restrict access to your site with HTTP authentication. Don't use Symfony2 security for that.

Leave your symfony2 app security as it will be in production mode and use apache .htaccess to restrict access to the site.

Documentation is here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html. You just have to add some directives in web/.htaccess, and create a user/password file as explained in the doc...

Comment: Thanks Pece. I would still prefer to have everything done on application level, rather than resort to Apache.

Comment: I have decided to go for your suggestion because it doesnt seem to be easy my way and, after all, it is good to implement things as another developer would expect.

Comment: I think this way is good if you just need to secure access without identifying users. Moreover, once they pass this temporary security, they see the future app as it will be, with the same login process.

Answer (score 0):

my solution in Symfony2, using the basic firewall of symfony (without FOSUserBundle):

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    redattore: { password: 'somePasswordHere', roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                    admin: { password: 'somePasswordHere', roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

It works perfectly for me. It's a very basic configuration - without hashing passwords, without data base provider ("providers:" section), without https connection (everything goes in plain text throughout the internet), without logout stuff and other nice features.
I hope it will help you.
With kind regards